# White Preloader Screen? (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3

I've made a preloader, it works fine, except the screen is white until about 75% loaded, the file is incredibly small (~10kb) so I was wondering if it's because of that as when I used a 1.4mb image for testing it was only white until about 3% (which I was fine with).

You can find a .swf here: http://www.newgrounds.com/dump/item/f55c55059d9b3bcbec03c08c492ab739

Code on frame 1:

```
stop();
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameChecker1);
function frameChecker1(event:Event):void {
trace("Frame entered.");
var loaded:Number = this.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;
var total:Number = this.loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
var percent:Number = loaded/total;
var percentRounded:uint = percent * 100;
loadingBar.scaleX = percent;
textLoading.text = percentRounded + "%";
if (total == loaded) {
    buttonPlay.alpha = percent;
}
else {
    buttonPlay.alpha = percent/2;
}
if (total == loaded) {
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameChecker1);
}
}
buttonPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playClick);
function playClick (event:MouseEvent){
        play();
    }
```

Comment: You should use a preloader wrapper.  Once you build one, you can use it on any swf.  Here's a video tutorial:  http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=85

Answer (score 0):

First frame needs to be fully loaded for it to be visible. If you have dynamic objects (symbols you can attach with code) you will have to export them elsewhere (frame 2). You can go into Library > "Your Symbol" > Right Click > Properties, and uncheck "Export in frame 1".

[image]

Now you'll have manually place these objects somewhere. Usually you just dump all dynamics objects on frame two, and you never really use that frame for anything else. This will guarantee all your objects are loaded on frame two, allowing your frame 1 to display the progress.

[image]