# White Screen On Preloader? (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have made other topics for this, and my knowledge has progressed a bit. On the first frame I have a preloader and a play button, which sends the user to another frame. I'm getting the white screen for about up to 90% of the preloaders completion. I'm not exporting anything for actionscript and nothing is exporting for frame 1, everything is within one document and was made within flash.

I carried on coding to see if the problem would resolve itself, after adding another frame and coding some buttons etc, I noticed that the first frame had jumped from 7kb to about 65 kb, all the other frames remained relatively the same size.

Just ask if you need to see the code, I'm using bytesLoaded and bytesTotal. I know the first frame needs to load, but why the hell has it jumped in size?

In advance, all answers are appreciated.

Comment: I already answered you.  You can keep asking but the answer is the same.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your response.

Comment: possible duplicate of [White Preloader Screen? (AS3)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474607/white-preloader-screen-as3)